# Reference previous overlay without having to write its name in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

## Table of contents

- The context
- Reference previous overlay in a chain of overlays is mandatory
- The question

## The context

I'm generating a ffmpeg command programmatically because I want to show multiple lines at different times. The algorith that I've written generates a string that is then passed to the flag `-filter_complex`, my algorithm is somewhat complex because I need to reference the name of the previous overlay. It would be simpler if I knew how to reference the previous overlay without having to explicitly write its name. I want to know if it is possible to do that.

## Reference previous overlay in a chain of overlays is mandatory

I didn't find documentation that states that referencing the previous overlay in a chain of overlays is mandatory, so I proved this point with minimal working examples, this section shows them. If you believe the same, skip this section. If you believe the opposite, please let me know how to do it.

The following command generates a blue background with two horizontal lines.

```sh
ffmpeg \
    -v error \
    -y \
    -f lavfi \
    -i color=blue:s=1920x1080:d=10 \
    -filter_complex "color=white@1:1920x10 [myline1]; \
       [0:v][myline1] overlay=0:360:shortest=1 [overlay1]; \
       color=white@1:1920x10 [myline2]; \
       [overlay1][myline2] overlay=0:720:shortest=1" \
    output.avi
```

[image]

The following command is similar to the 1st command. The difference is that, in the 2nd overlay, we don't reference the 1st overlay. The command **doesn't** exit successfully.

```sh
ffmpeg \
    -v error \
    -y \
    -f lavfi \
    -i color=blue:s=1920x1080:d=10 \
    -filter_complex "color=white@1:1920x10 [myline1]; \
       [0:v][myline1] overlay=0:360:shortest=1 [overlay1]; \
       color=white@1:1920x10 [myline2]; \
       [0:v][myline2] overlay=0:720:shortest=1" \
    output.avi
echo Exit code: $?
```

```
Filter overlay:default has an unconnected output
Exit code: 1
```

The following command is similar to the 1st command. The difference is that, in the 2nd overlay, we don't reference the 1st overlay and the 1st overlay is not given a name. The command exits successfully, but the second overlay doesn't seem to have an effect in the resulting video.

```sh
ffmpeg \
    -v error \
    -y \
    -f lavfi \
    -i color=blue:s=1920x1080:d=10 \
    -filter_complex "color=white@1:1920x10 [myline1]; \
       [0:v][myline1] overlay=0:360:shortest=1; \
       color=white@1:1920x10 [myline2]; \
       [0:v][myline2] overlay=0:720:shortest=1" \
    output.avi
echo Exit code: $?
```

```
Exit code: 0
```

[image]

## The question

The following command generates a blue background with two horizontal lines.

```sh
ffmpeg \
    -v error \
    -y \
    -f lavfi \
    -i color=blue:s=1920x1080:d=10 \
    -filter_complex "color=white@1:1920x10 [myline1]; \
       [0:v][myline1] overlay=0:100:shortest=1 [overlay1]; \
       color=white@1:1920x10 [myline2]; \
       [overlay1][myline2] overlay=0:200:shortest=1 [overlay2]; \
       color=white@1:1920x10 [myline3]; \
       [overlay2][myline3] overlay=0:300:shortest=1" \
    output.avi
```

[image]

Instead of writing the comamnd shown above, I wish I could write the command shown below, so my question is: Is there a variable to reference the previous overlay?

```sh
ffmpeg \
    -v error \
    -y \
    -f lavfi \
    -i color=blue:s=1920x1080:d=10 \
    -filter_complex "color=white@1:1920x10 [myline1]; \
       [0:v][myline1] overlay=0:100:shortest=1 [overlay1]; \
       color=white@1:1920x10 [myline2]; \
       [<<REFERENCE PREVIOUS OVERLAY>>][myline2] overlay=0:200:shortest=1 [overlay2]; \
       color=white@1:1920x10 [myline3]; \
       [<<REFERENCE PREVIOUS OVERLAY>>][myline3] overlay=0:300:shortest=1" \
    output.avi
```

This question just popped in my mind because I recalled that ffmpeg define other variables, e.g. `main_w` and `overlay_w`, so it is likely that it has a variable for referencing the previous overlay.